# Running Hadoop in virtual environment

Tags: hadoop, virtualization, hadoop-yarn

I would like to know whether I should expect problems when having Hadoop cluster on virtual instead of physical machines?

I'm mostly worried about using the same hard drive, I read that I should count for 1-2 containers per drive,but in my case only one drive will exist. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930439/hadoop-virtual-cluster-vs-single-machine

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends upon how much size are you allocating for containers. Of course there would be limitation to number of containers if you have restriction to the memory.
I can highlight few points which can be considered while running hadoop cluster in virtual environment:

1. Network configuration in case of multi node cluster
2. Obvious the performance of application
3. Affect on scalability as limited resources if you are planning to run the cluster on host which has low configuration hardware